# why does inline float printing goes wrong with python

Tags: python, floating-point

I got a strange rounding effect when printing.
Using the below python code, I tried to put it all on one line.
However, the variable **s** got wrongly printed in the first line it seems

```
s = gb.score(train, y)
if (s>0.96)&(s<1.0):
   print("LR: {0:.3f} estimators: {0:.3f} score: {0:.16f}".format(learning_rate,est,s))
   print (s)
```

The output I get from this is :

LR: 0.003 estimators: 0.003 score: 0.0025000000000000
0.9696969696969697

why is S rounded to 0.00250000 on the first line ??
I would like it to be displayed as in the second row.

Comment: You're printing `learning_rate` three times

Comment: learn rate = 0.03, estimator = 300  (also that one goes wrong now i see), i mainly focused on score

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `0` in `{0:.16f}` will insert the first argument. That's why in all three places only the value of your `learning_rate` is inserted and formatted.

Try

```
print("LR: {0:.3f} estimators: {1:.3f} score: {2:.16f}".format(learning_rate,est,s))
```

or just using the order of the arguments:

```
print("LR: {:.3f} estimators: {:.3f} score: {:.16f}".format(learning_rate,est,s))
```

To avoid confusion you can also use names for inserting:

```
print("LR: {learningrate:.3f} estimators: {estimators:.3f} score: {score:.16f}".format(learningrate=learning_rate,estimators=est,score=s))
```